# como pegar a key em um while loop?

Tags: php, loop

Digamos que eu tenha um array associativo

```
$array=array(
     "teste" => "1".
     "teste2" => "2"
);

foreach($array AS $key=>$arr){
    echo $key;
}
```

como faz com loop? tem algum modo?

Comment: Bom, isso ai não é um array multidimensional, é um array de 2 indices associativos.

Comment: Sim é possível também com a função `key()`!

Comment: foreach é loop. Acho melhor perguntar como faz com "while", se a dúvida é essa (no título já tem, digo no corpo da pergunta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer de duas formas. Dado o array:

```
$array = array(
    'teste' => '1',
    'teste2' => '2'
);
```

**1.** Utilizando o método [current()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.current.php), o qual devolve o elemento atual do array, junto com os métodos [key()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.key.php) para pegar a chave do elemento atual, e [next()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.next.php) para avançar o ponteiro interno do array (para que `current()` pegue o elemento seguinte na próxima iteração):

```
while ($value = current($array)) {
    echo key($array) . "\n";
    next($array);
}
```

**2.** Utilizando o método [each()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.each.php), que faz o mesmo que os 3 métodos acima juntos: devolve o par chave/valor atual do array, e avança o ponteiro. Exemplo:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
    echo $key . "\n";
}
```

Veja o código executando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6czrsT).